# R: Count number of values from one column according to values in another column

Tags: r

I have a bit of an unclear question, so I hope I can explain this properly.
I am using R. I know for loops can be slow in R, but for me it would be ok to use a for loop in this case.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    id_A    id_B    id_C    calc_A  calc_B  calc_C  
1   x,z     d       g,f        1        1       5
2   x,y,z   d,e     f          1        2       8
3   y,z     d,e     g          6        7       1
```

I also have a vector with the names `c('A', 'B', 'C', etc.)`
What I want to do is to count for every row, how many `id`’s have a `calc` <= 2.
`id_A` is linked to `calc_A`, etc.

For example, for the first row A and B have `calc` values <= 2, together A and B have 3 `id`'s.
So the output will be something like this:

```
   count
1   3
2   5
3   1
```

Comment: Could there be duplicate ids in different id-columns? e.g. could id_b contain x as id although it is present in id_a? And if that's possible, how would this be counted?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit messy, but this should do the trick (for data.frame `d`):

```
# store indices of calc columns and id columns
calc.cols <- grep('^calc', names(d))
id.cols <- grep('^id', names(d))

sapply(split(d, seq_len(nrow(d))), function(x) {
  length(unique(unlist(strsplit(paste(x[, id.cols][which(x[, calc.cols] <= 2)], 
                                      collapse=','), ','))))
})

# 1 2 3 
# 3 5 1
```

Comment: @Mary - this assumes that the order of the `id` columns is the same as the order of the `calc` columns... is this the case for your data? (i.e. if `id` columns appear in the order `A`, `B`, `C`, then so do the `calc` columns.)

Comment: Yes this is also the case for my data. 
Only in my real data there are other columns before these with other information that is not relevant for this now. 
(The vector with the names is not in the same order though)

Comment: @Mary I'm not sure what the relevance of the vector with names is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `ID` columns and the `calc` columns are in the same order

```
 library(stringr)
 indx <- sapply(df[,1:3], str_count, ",")+1
 indx[df[,4:6] >2] <- NA
 df$count <- rowSums(indx,na.rm=TRUE)
 df
 #   id_A id_B id_C calc_A calc_B calc_C count
 #1   x,z    d  g,f      1      1      5     3
 #2 x,y,z  d,e    f      1      2      8     5
 #3   y,z  d,e    g      6      7      1     1
```

#### Update

Suppose, your dataset is not in the same order

```
 set.seed(42)
 df1 <- df[,sample(6)]
 library(gtools)
 df2 <-df1[,mixedorder(names(df1))]
 #    calc_A calc_B calc_C  id_A id_B id_C
 #1      1      1      5   x,z    d  g,f
 #2      1      2      8 x,y,z  d,e    f
 #3      6      7      1   y,z  d,e    g

 id1 <- grep("^id", colnames(df2))
 calc1 <- grep("^calc", colnames(df2)) 

 indx1 <-sapply(df2[, id1], str_count, ",")+1
 indx1[df2[, calc1] >2] <- NA
 df1$count <- rowSums(indx1, na.rm=TRUE)
 df1
 #     calc_C calc_B id_B id_C calc_A  id_A count
 #1      5      1    d  g,f      1   x,z     3
 #2      8      2  d,e    f      1 x,y,z     5
 #3      1      7  d,e    g      6   y,z     1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id_A = c("x,z", "x,y,z", "y,z"), id_B = c("d", 
 "d,e", "d,e"), id_C = c("g,f", "f", "g"), calc_A = c(1L, 1L, 
 6L), calc_B = c(1L, 2L, 7L), calc_C = c(5L, 8L, 1L)), .Names = c("id_A", 
"id_B", "id_C", "calc_A", "calc_B", "calc_C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Comment: If you look at Mary's comments, id's and calc's columns can be more than 3 of each and their positions are not fixed so `1:3` and `4:6` can't always work...

Comment: @CathG More columns doesn't matter as long as they are in the same order.

Comment: I said that because you are using `df[,1:3]` and `df[,4:6]` : won't your solution yield weird counts if there are also `id_D` and `calc_D` (so ids columns would be `1:4` and calcs columns, `5:8`) ?

Comment: @akrun This is the one I would take home today. I can read lines. Thanks as usual.

Comment: @jazzurro No problem.  I don't know if this is efficient or not, but using `rowSums` should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is less messy than jbaums solution but here is another option :

```
mydf<-data.frame(id_A=c("x,y","x,y,z","y,z"),id_B=c("d","d,e","d,e"),id_C=c("g,f","f","g"),
                 calc_A=c(1,1,6),calc_B=c(1,2,7),calc_C=c(5,8,1),stringsAsFactors=F)



mydf$count<-apply(mydf,1,function(rg,namesrg){
                     rg_calc<-rg[grep("calc",namesrg)]
                     rg_ids<-rg[grep("id",namesrg)]
                     idsinf2<-which(as.numeric( rg_calc)<=2)
                     ttids<-unlist(sapply(rg_ids[gsub("calc","id",names(rg_calc[idsinf2]))],function(id){strsplit(id,",")[[1]]}))
                     return(length(ttids))
                    },colnames(mydf))


>  mydf
   id_A id_B id_C calc_A calc_B calc_C count
1   x,y    d  g,f      1      1      5     3
2 x,y,z  d,e    f      1      2      8     5
3   y,z  d,e    g      6      7      1     1
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I am not sure at which positions the id's and the calc's are in the dataframe (it can also be more or less than 4 columns)

Comment: @Mary I updated my answer to take names of columns into account, columns can be in any order